# MassTransit - Sending Message to Azure Service Bus from Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, masstransit

I want to send messages to the Azure Service Bus queue from an Azure Function. I registered MassTransit in the WebAPI projects and managed to send messages to Service Bus. But for Azure Functions, all the examples I find online set it up as a Consumer. But I want to use it only as a Producer.

**I managed to create a working code but looking for something more concrete.**

For the WebAPI projects, I registered MassTransit as follows,

```cs
// Startup.cs 

public static IServiceCollection RegisterAzureServiceBus(this IServiceCollection services){
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.UsingAzureServiceBus((ctx, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host("connection-string", host =>
            {
                host.RetryLimit = 10;
                host.RetryMaxBackoff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            });
        });
    });
    
    services.AddOptions<MassTransitHostOptions>().Configure(options =>
    {
        options.StopTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    });
    
    services.AddSingleton<IServiceBus, MassTransitAzureServiceBus>(); // IServiceBus is my contract with MassTransit
}
```

When I add the same thing in the Function App, I get the following error,

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: Invalid host services detected. 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost: The following service registrations did not match the expected services: [Invalid] ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService, Lifetime: Singleton, ImplementationType: MassTransit.MassTransitHostedService, MassTransit, Version=8.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b8e0e9f2f1e657fa.
```

Now, for Azure Function, I see that there is another signature `AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions()`. I looked into its code and found that it is removing MassTransitHostedService from the DI Container. So I added the following after registering MassTransit.

```cs
builder.Services.RemoveMassTransitHostedService();
```

The previous error is now gone, but it complains about `ISendEndpointProvider` having "scoped" lifetime when `MassTransitAzureServiceBus` has a lifetime of `singleton`. I set the registeration of my contract to scoped as follows:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IServiceBus, MassTransitAzureServiceBus>();
```

Now I can send messages to Azure Service Bus!

So eventually my MassTransit registration becomes,

```cs
public static IServiceCollection RegisterAzureServiceBus(this IServiceCollection services){
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        x.UsingAzureServiceBus((ctx, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host("connection-string", host =>
            {
                host.RetryLimit = 10;
                host.RetryMaxBackoff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            });
        });
    });
    
    services.AddOptions<MassTransitHostOptions>().Configure(options =>
    {
        options.StopTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    });

    builder.Services.RemoveMassTransitHostedService();
    
    services.AddScoped<IServiceBus, MassTransitAzureServiceBus>(); // IServiceBus is my contract with MassTransit
}
```

Is this the correct way to use it for Azure Functions? I'm assuming there is a cleaner way which I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

The [sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-AzureFunction/blob/master/src/Sample.AzureFunction/SubmitOrderHttpFunction.cs) shows how to use MassTransit to produce messages in other trigger types.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code which shows where it's producing the message? 
This looks like it's only showing the consumer side.

Comment: The linked code file is only producing a message (via the request client). This could easily be replaced by `IPublishEndpoint` or `ISendEndpointProvider`.